# Medical Risk Factor Datasets - heart disease, metabolic syndrome diet

Tags: medical, food

I am interested in learning data and in understanding health. I have listened to a lot of Robert Lustig, M.D. the past several months. I know about Framingham's study and the China Study and Ancel Key's work.

I was wondering if the data for any of these is available.

My goal is to do multivariate linear regressions on the data available and find what is to be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free MIT Online Course ["The Analytics Edge"](https://www.edx.org/course/the-analytics-edge) used a subset of the Framingham study in their Unit 3 as an introduction to Linear Regression.  (1 Table, 4000 rows, ~20 columns, no NAs).

You can enroll and see if they still use that example, as they did in 2015.

Otherwise take a look at the [NHANES dataset](https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes/) - that's the National Health and Nutrition Examination Survey of the USA. But with this dataset you'll have to do a lot more preprocessing (because of the many NAs).